# Get entry point of llvm::module

Tags: ios, llvm, bitcode

I've parsed a bitcode file with `llvm::parseBitcodeFile` and I've got the `llvm::Module`, I can iterate over the functions of the module:

```
std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module>& M = *parsed;
for(auto& func : M->functions())
{
    // how to identify the entry point?
}
```

And I would like to identify the entry point of the module (and thus of the application - if there are multiple modules, one of them should have an entry point..) , but I wasn't able to find anything in `func` to do that, what would be the proper way to identify the entry point? (In most cases it will be the `main` function, so looking for the name seems to work, but not always).

More generically, I'm looking for a way to find the entry point (if any - perhaps `main`) of a/many bitcode file that I'm given..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "entry point" in a LLVM Module. Entry point is a feature of an application and could be very different depending on e.g. source language, etc. Also, since LLVM Module represents somehow a translation unit there might be no "main function at all.

If you happen to know the name of the function you're looking for, then you can certainly use `Module::getFunction` call to perform name-based lookup.

Comment: But bitcode must contain a reference to something that is an entry point for the application since bitcode can be translated to final binary, perhaps using `llvm::Module` is not the correct approach, what would you suggest to do in order to find the entry point of a bitcode file?

Comment: The entry point to an application is defined by name, typically main(). Bitcode doesn't define it, or treat that function specially. There's no requirement that main() be in a .bc file either. It's legal to use LLVM to build some parts of an application and use something else for the rest. (In fact, I do that myself. The thing I'm working on right now uses an executable built using LLVM in one way, linked to a few .so files built using LLVM in a very different way and some more .so files built using another compiler.)

Comment: @fjanisze If you know the source language, then you'd simply query by name the corresponding function. Note that "entry point" is a binary image thing and usually necessary lifting is done by runtime. For example, in ELF world one specifies that entry point symbol is "_start" (via linker option / linker script), then "_start" being part of language runtime does necessary initialization, etc. and then calls corresponding "main" function. But again, usually lots of things happens before "main" is called. E.g. in C/C++ world at least static ctors are executed.